# Multi-dimensional char array prints within function, but not when passed to another function

Tags: c

I am attempting to write data into a multi-dimensional array, and then pass the array as a `const char**` to another function.  When I print the `char*` locally in the function in which it is declared, everything works as expected.  But, when I try to print the array of `char*` in another function, they are all empty strings.

I am using the following code:

```
void my_print (const char** lines, unsigned int num)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lines[%d]:  %s", i, lines[i]);
    }
}

void my_func ()
{
    char cfg[2][200];
    unsigned int value = 5;

    snprintf(cfg[0], 200, "one two three\n");
    snprintf(cfg[1], 200, "my value = %u\n", value);

    fprintf(stderr, "lines[0] = %slines[1] = %s\n", cfg[0], cfg[1]);

    my_print((const char**) cfg, 2);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
lines[0] = one two three
lines[1] = my value = 5
lines[0]:
lines[1]:
```

If instead, of the given `my_func`, I use the following:

```
void my_func ()
{
    char* cfg[2];
    unsigned int value = 5;

    cfg[0] = malloc(200);
    cfg[1] = malloc(200);
    snprintf(cfg[0], 200, "one two three\n");
    snprintf(cfg[1], 200, "my value = %u\n", value);

    fprintf(stderr, "lines[0] = %slines[1] = %s\n", cfg[0], cfg[1]);

    my_print((const char**) cfg, 2);
}
```

Then, everything works, and I get:

```
lines[0] = one two three
lines[1] = my value = 5
lines[0]: one two three
lines[1]: my value = 5
```

So, what is happening in the background here?  Why do I need to use `malloc` in order for `my_print` to be able to print my strings?

Thanks you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **An array is not a pointer**

Arrays *decay* into pointers to their first elements, but that only happens at the **first** dimension.  So a 2D array does *not* decay into a pointer to a pointer, it only decays into a pointer to an array, so that is what you must pass to your function:

```
// lines is of type "pointer to array 200 of const char"
void my_print (const char (*lines)[200], unsigned int num)
```

This line of code is very, very wrong:

```
my_print((const char**) cfg, 2);
```

You probably inserted the cast to `const char**` to silence the compiler.  Do **not** do that -- the compiler is trying to tell you that you're doing something wrong!  Shutting it up is the wrong thing to do.  With the above change to the definition of `my_print`, you do not need any cast:

```
my_print(cfg, 2);
```

Comment: The fact that the 2D array does not decay into a pointer to a pointer was the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation given is good: pointer-to-pointer is *not* the same thing as a multi-dimensional array.

Plainly explained, a 2-dimensional array with the syntax

char cfg[2][200];

is guaranteed to be allocated in adjacent memory cells. A 2-dimensional pointer-to-pointer array allocated with malloc will *not* be alloced in adjacent memory cells, it will be all over the heap. Because each time you call malloc, you will allocate a new segment. Making generic functions for multi-dimensional arrays in C is quite tricky because of this.